# My site keeps showing redirect loop ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm having issues rendering my site when I type in the following URLs:

http://www.onvia.com/hello

I get a redirect loop ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

I can see my page if I go to http://www.onvia.com/hello/index.html. Also, I can see other files in that directory like http://www.onvia.com/hello/hello.txt

It's not just that folder. It happens also to:

http://www.onvia.com/hello2
- I get the error, but if I go to http://www.onvia.com/hello2/index.html the page renders fine and I don't get an error.

What am I doing incorrectly on my .htaccess file?

I use Drupal as my CMS, but these files are outside of Drupal.

Here's my .htaccess file:

```
    #
# Apache/PHP/Drupal settings:
#

# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>

# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Make Drupal handle any 404 errors.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

# Override PHP settings that cannot be changed at runtime. See
# sites/default/default.settings.php and drupal_environment_initialize() in
# includes/bootstrap.inc for settings that can be changed at runtime.

# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc                 off
  php_flag magic_quotes_sybase              off
  php_flag register_globals                 off
  php_flag session.auto_start               off
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_flag mbstring.encoding_translation    off
</IfModule>

# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  ExpiresActive Off

  # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
  ExpiresDefault A1209600

  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    # Do not allow PHP scripts to be cached unless they explicitly send cache
    # headers themselves. Otherwise all scripts would have to overwrite the
    # headers set by mod_expires if they want another caching behavior. This may
    # fail if an error occurs early in the bootstrap process, and it may cause
    # problems if a non-Drupal PHP file is installed in a subdirectory.
    ExpiresActive Off
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # Block access to "hidden" directories whose names begin with a period. This
  # includes directories used by version control systems such as Subversion or
  # Git to store control files. Files whose names begin with a period, as well
  # as the control files used by CVS, are protected by the FilesMatch directive
  # above.
  #
  # NOTE: This only works when mod_rewrite is loaded. Without mod_rewrite, it is
  # not possible to block access to entire directories from .htaccess, because
  # <DirectoryMatch> is not allowed here.
  #
  # If you do not have mod_rewrite installed, you should remove these
  # directories from your webroot or otherwise protect them from being
  # downloaded.
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

  # If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
  # can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
  # URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  # RewriteBase /

  #get rid of trailing slashes
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?onvia\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L] 

  # Redirect https requests to http, but exclude certain requests for assets in js/css/media folders 
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/media/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/
  RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

  ##########################################################
  # THESE ARE THE PROMO ADS THAT SHOW UP IN THE ONVIA GUIDE
  # THE PLATFORM CALLS A FIXED URL WITH A COBRAND IN THE URL AND WE
  # REDIRECT IT TO THE APPROPRIATE ASSET ON OUR SIDE
  ##########################################################

  ##########################################################
  # Pipeline Guide Promotional Units
  ##########################################################

  # REDIRECT NTLT MARKETING PROMO TO THE ONVIA ADVANTAGE SITE
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} utm_campaign=product_onvia_pipeline_email
  RewriteRule ^promo/onvia-guide-email$ http://support.onvia.com/pipeline [R=302,L,NC]

  # REDIRECT NTLT MARKETING PROMO IMAGE TO THE RIGHT PROMO IMAGE
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} utm_campaign=product_onvia_pipeline_email
  RewriteRule ^sites/default/files/daily-guide/productbanner200x215.jpg$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/sites/default/files/daily-guide/pipeline_banner200x215.jpg [R=302,L,NC]

  # REDIRECT NTLT PRODUCT PROMO TO THE USERVOICE SITE
  # NO SPECIAL ROUTING FOR THIS ONE (USING THE DEFAULT)
           # RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} utm_campaign=marketing_onvia_pipeline_email
           # RewriteRule ^promo/onvia-guide-email$ http://www.onvia.com/business-resources/white-papers/10-hotspots-in-government-contracting   [R=302,L,NC]

  # REDIRECT NTLT PRODUCT PROMO IMAGE REQUEST TO THE RIGHT PROMO IMAGE
  # NO SPECIAL ROUTING FOR THIS ONE (USING THE DEFAULT)
           # RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} utm_campaign=marketing_onvia_pipeline_email
           # RewriteRule ^sites/default/files/daily-guide/banner200x215.jpg$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/sites/default/files/daily-guide/pipeline_marketing_banner200x215.jpg [R=302,L,NC]

  ##########################################################
  # NTLT - No Touch/Low Touch (ECommerce) Custom Guide Promotional Units
  ##########################################################

  # REDIRECT NTLT MARKETING PROMO TO THE ONVIA ADVANTAGE SITE
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} utm_campaign=marketing_guide_email_NTLT
  RewriteRule ^promo/onvia-guide-email$ http://www.onvia.com/business-resources/white-papers/10-hotspots-in-government-contracting [R=302,L,NC]

  # REDIRECT NTLT MARKETING PROMO IMAGE TO THE RIGHT PROMO IMAGE
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} utm_campaign=marketing_guide_email_NTLT
  RewriteRule ^sites/default/files/daily-guide/banner200x215.jpg$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/sites/default/files/daily-guide/NTLT_banner200x215.jpg [R=302,L,NC]

  # REDIRECT NTLT PRODUCT PROMO TO THE USERVOICE SITE
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} utm_campaign=product_guide_email_NTLT
  RewriteRule ^promo/product-onvia-guide-email$ http://onvia.uservoice.com/  [R=302,L,NC]

  # REDIRECT NTLT PRODUCT PROMO IMAGE REQUEST TO THE RIGHT PROMO IMAGE
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} utm_campaign=product_guide_email_NTLT
  RewriteRule ^sites/default/files/daily-guide/productbanner200x215.jpg$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/sites/default/files/daily-guide/NTLT_productbanner200x215.jpg [R=302,L,NC]

  ##########################################################
  # DEFAULT/FALLBACK Custom Guide Promotional Units
  ##########################################################

  # REDIRECT ALL OTHER MARKETING PROMO REQUESTS TO THE ONVIA ADVANTAGE SITE
  RewriteRule ^promo/onvia-guide-email$ http://www.onvia.com/business-resources/white-papers/10-hotspots-in-government-contracting [R=302,L,NC]

  # REDIRECT ALL OTHER PRODUCT PROMO REQUESTS TO THE ONVIA ADVANTAGE SITE
  RewriteRule ^promo/product-onvia-guide-email$ http://www.onvia.com/business-resources/how-to-build-a-future-sales-pipeline-using-onvia-spending-forecast-center [R=302,L,NC]

  ##########################################################
  # END OF PROMOTIONAL AD UNIT REDIRECTS IN ONVIA GUIDE
  ##########################################################

  # ONVIA 301 Redirects
  RewriteRule ^support/$ http://support.onvia.com [R=301,L,NC]
  RewriteRule ^support$ http://support.onvia.com [R=301,L,NC]
  RewriteRule ^forms/DS-SubscriptionRequest$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/demandstar-subscriptions [R=301,L,NC]
  RewriteRule ^notification-sign$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/wapp [R=301,L,NC]
  RewriteRule ^sites/all/themes/onvia/img/logo.gif$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/sites/default/files/logo.gif [R=301,L,NC]
  RewriteRule ^partners$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/partners/business-associations [R=301,L,NC]
  RewriteRule ^content/demandstar_subscriptions$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/demandstar-subscriptions [R=301,L,NC]
  RewriteRule ^support/video_01.html$ http://support.onvia.com/product-guide/opportunity-notification-introduction [R=301,L,NC]
  RewriteRule ^sites/all/themes/onvia/css/nav.css$ http://%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301,L,NC]
  RewriteRule ^sites/all/themes/onvia/css/boxes.css$ http://%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301,L,NC]
  RewriteRule ^sites/all/themes/onvia/css/links.css$ http://%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301,L,NC]
  RewriteRule ^sites/all/themes/onvia/css/common.css$ http://%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301,L,NC]
  RewriteRule ^fp/Default.aspx$ http://%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301,L,NC]
  RewriteRule ^agency/testimonials.asp http://%{HTTP_HOST}/solutions/demandstar-onvia/testimonials [R=301,L,NC]
  RewriteRule ^blog/how-to-find-upcoming-term-contracts-in-state-and-local-government-using-term-contract-center http://%{HTTP_HOST}/blog/how-to-find-active-term-contracts-in-state-and-local-government-using-term-contract-center [R=301,L,NC]
  RewriteRule ^winning-business-with-city-agencies-spotlight-austin http://%{HTTP_HOST}/business-resources/winning-business-with-city-agencies [R=301,L,NC]
  RewriteRule ^how-to-build-a-future-sales-pipeline-using-onvia-spending-forecast-center http://%{HTTP_HOST}/business-resources/how-to-build-a-future-sales-pipeline-using-onvia-spending-forecast-center [R=301,L,NC]
  RewriteRule ^blog/the-growth-of-gamification-what-it-means-for-schools-and-districts http://%{HTTP_HOST}/blog/gamification-K-12-teachers-game-the-system-to-innovate-education [R=301,L,NC]
  RewriteRule ^blog/infographic-voip http://%{HTTP_HOST}/blog/infographic-targeting-government-voip-market [R=301,L,NC]
  RewriteRule ^free-agency-form https://www.demandstar.com/supplier/memberwiz/address.asp?mi=2035150&ai=1927026&wizmode=1&mode=s&ag=1 [R=301,L,NC]

  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

  # Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files.
  # Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
    RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
      # Serve correct encoding type.
      Header set Content-Encoding gzip
      # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What URL are you entering in browser that is causing redirect loop?

Comment: Http://www.onvia.com/hello

Comment: Also http://www.onvia.com/hello2

Comment: So it's any url string that has http://www.onvia.com/foldername but the page comes up if I type in file names under that folder such as http://www onvia.com/hello/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Change your trailing slash rule to this:

```
#get rid of trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.